# Does magnetic field $B\sin{\omega t}$ break time-reversal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, time-evolution, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider a pulse magnetic field $$B\hat{z}\,e^{-t^2/t_0^2}\cos(\omega t)$$ shone to some physical system. Let's say the system at $t\ll -t_0$ is at equilibrium and does not break time-reversal symmetry (T). After the pulse ($t\gg t_0$), is it *possible* that the system can exhibit some T-breaking feature (e.g., magnetization or whatever)?
Note that I'm only asking about the conceptual possibility restricted by symmetry; the real situation certainly depends on system details.

My naive feeling is this expectation is true and does not quite rely on the pulse time dependence. But I found that under time-reversal $B\rightarrow-B,t\rightarrow-t$ we have $B\cos(\omega t)\rightarrow-B\cos(\omega t)$ while $B\sin(\omega t)\rightarrow B\sin(\omega t)$. This seems to say if we instead use $B\hat{z}\,e^{-t^2/t_0^2}\sin(\omega t)$ for the pulse, it does not break T-symmetry and hence no possible T-breaking phenomenon after the pulse?

I feel there's some stupid flaw in the reasoning. Which is true?

Comment: Doesn't $B \, \sin(\omega t)$ instead of $B \, \cos(\omega t)$ acquire a phase under $t \to -t$, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Yejus Sorry, what do you mean by a phase?